# screen sharing on webrtc (How can add to track?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, nodes, screensharing

```
pc.ontrack = (e) => {
let _remoteStream = null
let remoteStreams = this.state.remoteStreams
let remoteVideo = {}
// 1. check if stream already exists in remoteStreams
const rVideos = this.state.remoteStreams.filter(stream => stream.id === socketID)
// 2. if it does exist then add track
if (rVideos.length) {
_remoteStream = rVideos[0].stream
_remoteStream.addTrack(e.track, _remoteStream)
remoteVideo = {
            ...rVideos[0],
stream: _remoteStream,
}
remoteStreams = this.state.remoteStreams.map(_remoteVideo => {
return _remoteVideo.id === remoteVideo.id && remoteVideo || _remoteVideo
})
} else {
// 3. if not, then create new stream and add track
_remoteStream = new MediaStream()
_remoteStream.addTrack(e.track, _remoteStream)
remoteVideo = {
id: socketID,
name: socketID,
stream: _remoteStream,
}
remoteStreams = [...this.state.remoteStreams, remoteVideo]
}
// const remoteVideo = {
//   id: socketID,
//   name: socketID,
//   stream: e.streams[0]
// }
this.setState(prevState => {
// If we already have a stream in display let it stay the same, otherwise use the latest stream
// const remoteStream = prevState.remoteStreams.length > 0 ? {} : { remoteStream: e.streams[0] }
const remoteStream = prevState.remoteStreams.length > 0 ? {} : { remoteStream: _remoteStream }
// get currently selected video
let selectedVideo = prevState.remoteStreams.filter(stream => stream.id === prevState.selectedVideo.id)
// if the video is still in the list, then do nothing, otherwise set to new video stream
selectedVideo = selectedVideo.length ? {} : { selectedVideo: remoteVideo }
return {
// selectedVideo: remoteVideo,
            ...selectedVideo,
// remoteStream: e.streams[0],
            ...remoteStream,
            remoteStreams, //: [...prevState.remoteStreams, remoteVideo]
}
})
}

            screenshare.onclick=function(){              
               navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints)       
               .then(success)
               .catch(failure)           
            }
```

this is my pc.ontrack code
and I added this button event to people can covert local streams to screen streams.
In aspect of current peer, the stream is changed.
How can I other people can see one people's screen sharing?

this is my pc.ontrack code
and I added this button event to people can covert local streams to screen streams.
In aspect of current peer, the stream is changed.
How can I other people can see one people's screen sharing?